# Path to a file in a different drive?

Tags: php, path, relative-path, absolute-path, opendir

My php file is here:
`D:/Appserv/www/x/y/file.php`

I want to load stuff from this folder:
`E:/foldie`

I don't know what path will lead me there.

```
$somePath="HELP ME HERE!!!!"  
$dir=opendir($somePath);

//looping through filenames
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    echo "$file\n";
}
```

Comment: Did you try E:/foldie? Because that should work unless there's some kind of permissions preventing it.

Comment: Precisely how does this fail?

Answer (score 5):

Use full Windows path to the file it should be working: "E:\folder\file.txt"

or just copy the file in the local/project directory for testing purpose.

Comment: make sure you escape your backslashes in strings (mentioned in Paul's post)

Answer (score 1):

Set `$somePath = "e:\\foldie"`.  If that doesn't work, please indicate to us how it fails.

[Edit:: make sure you escape your backslashes in strings]